# Introductory level text for differential games

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, optimal-control, differential-games

I am interested in studying differential games by myself. An introductory textbook will be great. For introductory, I mean that the book shall have the definitions to concept and theorem (with proof) used in differential games.

I took game theory course and measure-theoretic probability theory. Would like to know better about what kind of problems differential games deal with, and what that topic study about.

Can you guys recommend some intro books for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One book you could check out is [Chases and Escapes: The Mathematics of Pursuit and Evasion](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9700.html) by Paul J. Nahin. I saw it at my university library. It has some of the classic games.